# Avoid slugging Certain Views with Friendly_ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, friendly-id

When using friendly_id, views that don't necessarily need to show the user's screen name are being displayed. For example. `127.0.0.1:3000/users/info.todacken333` How can I avoid showing the username on views like settings or edit current_user.account, etc??

route.rb

```
get '/users/info', to: 'users#info'
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll be best looking at [`singular resources`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources):

```
#config/routes.rb
resource :users, only: :edit, path_names: { edit: "info" } #-> url.com/user/info

#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def edit
    # Use current_user in view
  end
end

#view
<%= link_to "Info", edit_user_path %>
```

The problem you have is that you're passing your `current_user` to your path helper (probably because it requires it). Using `singular resources` (above) will remove the need for that.

Comment: Thanks. I will make the necessary changes.